# Can't use 'this' inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, prototype

It seems that I can't use `this` inside of a `setInerval` function. Why is that? What is a elegant solution?

```js
<html>
<script>
var something = function(tMessage){
    this.message = tMessage;
};

something.prototype = {
    start : function(counter){
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += this.message + "+++<br />";
        var looper = setInterval(
            function(){
                // This is printing "undefined"
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += this.message + "<br />";
                if(!counter--)
                    clearInterval(looper);
            },
            20
        );
    }
};


window.onload = function(){
    var e = new something("hi");
    e.start(2);
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Edit

Thanks for the answers!! But can anyone explain the difference between sending an argument and setting and extra variable? Any memory issues?

Comment: Because this == window inside the setInterval() callback function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that when your function is invoked `this` refers to the global object. To preserve the current scope, you could make a closure:

```
    var looper = setInterval(
        (function(scope){
            return function(){
                // This will no longer be printing "undefined"
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += scope.message + "<br />";
                if(!counter--)
                    clearInterval(looper);
            };
         })(this),
        20
    );
```

Instead of handwaving and trying to explain closures (which I am still in the process of fully mastering), I will direct you to this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/1726343

Comment: Use arrow function instead: setInterval(() => { }, 20)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `this` because you are in a new function block. I'm always creating a local variable (I'm sure there's a better way):

```
var c = this;
setInterval(function(
   c.variable = 1;
), 100);
```

Comment: Although the answer is correct I wouldn't say (not to confuse) that you cannot use `this`. You can but it refers to different context.

Comment: I understood it right. The only reason that I accepted Asads answer, is that in the case of a parameter the "extra variable" has a smaller scope (less errors possible). Although I think this one is more readable. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I usually do this: `let self = this;` Super simple and gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Because question is tagged [prototypejs] but no one answer uses Prototype, I decided to write an answer which really uses Prototype ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsbFz/)).

```
var Something = Class.create({
    initialize: function(tMessage) {
        this.message = tMessage;
    },

    start: function(counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
        $("result").innerHTML += this.message + "+++<br />";
        this.looper = setInterval(this.addMessage.bind(this), 20);
    },

    addMessage: function() {
        $("result").innerHTML += this.message + "<br />";
        if (!this.counter--) {
            clearInterval(this.looper);
        }
    }
});

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var e = new Something("hi");
    e.start(2);
});
```

1. Use [Class.create()](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/create/) to make more elegant classes.
2. Use [$()](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) instead of `document.getElementById()`.
3. Use [document.observe("dom:loaded")](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/) instead of `window.onload`
4. Use [bind(this)](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bind/) to bind function to context.

The key point of question is in execution context of function. Wherever you use `this`, it just points to the current execution context. When you invoke `someObject.someFunction()` then `someFunction()` is executed in context of `someObject`, and `this` inside of `someFunction()` will point to `someObject`.

But you can make assignment `someOtherObject.someFunction = someObject.someFunction`, and then in `someOtherObject.someFunction()` `this` will point to `someOtherObject`.

Also you can pass reference to function into another function, as you did in `setInterval()`, and then execution context will be defined by `setInterval()` (actually it will be global context, i.e. `this===window`).

In order to bind execution context to the function (predefine context, override invoker's context) you need to use `.bind()` method. It returns new function, which will invoke your original function with your desired context no matter which context will be at the run time.

Comment: I retagged the question because I didn't know there is a library called 'prototypejs'.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
var self = this;
```

just before your call to setInterval and use self instead of this into the function defined in set*interval