# Error when trying to replace constructor variab

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a clock Class with infinite loop upon start function , by using explicitly declared variable for `temp`, it works normal.

```
class Clock{
    constructor({template}){ //template  = "h:m:s"
        this.template = template;
        this.timer;
    }

    render() {
        var temp = 'h:m:s';
        let date = new Date();
    
        let hours = date.getHours();
        if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
    
        let mins = date.getMinutes();
        if (mins < 10) mins = '0' + mins;
    
        let secs = date.getSeconds();
        if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;
    
        let output = temp
        .replace('h', hours)
        .replace('m', mins)
        .replace('s', secs);
    
        console.log(output);
      }

    stop(){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    start(){
        this.render();
        this.timer = setInterval(this.render,1000);
    }
}

var clock = new Clock({template :'h:m:s'});
clock.start();
```

Output:

```
13:53:54
13:53:55
13:53:56
13:53:57
13:53:58
13:53:59
...
```

Well as you can see, i have declared a constructor named template for future purpose in case the users want to use another form of time template , but when i'm trying to use the `this.template` variable on `temp`, it shows error like this

```
class Clock{
    constructor({template}){ //template  = "h:m:s"
        this.template = template;
        this.timer;
    }

    render() {
        var temp = this.template;
        let date = new Date();
    
        let hours = date.getHours();
        if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
    
        let mins = date.getMinutes();
        if (mins < 10) mins = '0' + mins;
    
        let secs = date.getSeconds();
        if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;
    
        let output = temp
        .replace('h', hours)
        .replace('m', mins)
        .replace('s', secs);
    
        console.log(output);
      }

    stop(){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    start(){
        this.render();
        this.timer = setInterval(this.render,1000);
    }
}

var clock = new Clock({template :'h:m:s'});
clock.start();
```

Output:

```
13:56:17
c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\IM-Sanbercode-Reactjs-Batch-27\Tugas-Harian-Part-1\Tugas-7\tugas7.js:94   
        .replace('h', hours)    
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 
'replace' of undefined
    at Timeout.render [as _onTimeout] (c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\IM-Sanbercode-Reactjs-Batch-27\Tugas-Harian-Part-1\Tugas-7\tugas7.js:94:10)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```

Any idea how might it happened?

Comment: `this.timer = setInterval(this.render,1000);` *looses* `this` inside `this.render`. Try `this.timer = setInterval(this.render.bind(this),1000);`

Comment: @Yoshi my personal preference is `setInterval(() => this.render(), 1000)` because it avoids the code looking like a `this` sandwich with method in the middle.

Comment: @Vlaz You're right, I would probably also use this. And thank you for finding the duplicate! My hope with [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) was that it might be a good starting point to follow when reading about the underlying *problem*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.timer = setInterval(() => this.render(), 1000);`

When you use `this.timer = setInterval(this.render, 1000);` the [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430571/cant-use-this-inside-setinterval/13430604#13430604) of `this` will be `Window` object, to define the scope to your object level, use arrow function as `this.timer = setInterval(() => this.render(), 1000);`

```js
class Clock {
  constructor({ template }) { //template  = "h:m:s"
    this.template = template;
    this.timer;
  }

  render() {
    var temp = this.template;
    let date = new Date();

    let hours = date.getHours();
    if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;

    let mins = date.getMinutes();
    if (mins < 10) mins = '0' + mins;

    let secs = date.getSeconds();
    if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;

    let output = temp
      .replace('h', hours)
      .replace('m', mins)
      .replace('s', secs);

    console.log(output);
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  start() {
    this.render();
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.render(), 1000);
  }
}

var clock = new Clock({ template: 'h:m:s' });
clock.start();
```

Comment: All of this is explained in the linked duplicate question...